# Outputting an ASP.NET Web Site's XML Comments

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, documentation, xml-comments

I would like to document my VB.NET web site's source code.

How can I convert XML comments in a VB.NET ASP.NET web site to an XML documentation file?

I do not see an option to generate an XML documentation file in the VS web site's property pages.

Comment: Something like this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

Comment: I am using vb.net and have created website that is the reason i am not able see xml generate file option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With clarification that the question relates to a *VB.NET* ASP.NET *web site*, consider the following based on a [related discussion in MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25237c35-c861-4024-a3cb-849fcddd51b6/xml-documentation-for-aspnet-vbnet-website?forum=visualstudiogeneral):

1. I confirmed that [GhostDoc Pro](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) can at least build a help file for a VS VB.NET web site based on its XML comments.  Unfortunately the free version of GhostDoc cannot build a help file; but a personal license for of GhostDoc Pro is pretty inexpensive; and I have found GhostDoc Pro useful enough more generally to be worth buying.
2. Also, Sandcastle Help File Builder (SHFB) - which is free and I also use & love - ostensibly can facilitate outputting an XML documentation file and build a help file for a VS VB.NET web site.  As with most things S(HFB), I expect this *is* true...but will also require committment to take to the end zone.

See the "Documenting Website and Web Service Website Projects" section of SHFB documentation's [Documenting Web Projects](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/?topic=html/94c7f744-9b90-4254-93ab-9b15f47d9f42.htm) topic for more information about the SHFB option.

I confirmed that the reportedly required `EWSoftware.CodeDom.dll` is included with SHFB's extras (under `Sandcastle\Extras` with a default installation) - alongside its related help file.

Also, the aforementioned SHFB documentation explains that you will need to add a section like the following to your VB.NET web site's `Web.config` in order to leverage `EWSoftware.CodeDom.dll`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        compilerOptions="/docpath:C:\Publish\Docs"
        type="EWSoftware.CodeDom.VBCodeProviderWithDocs,
              EWSoftware.CodeDom, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
              PublicKeyToken=d633d7d5b41cbb65">
        <!-- NOTE: Change value to "v3.5" for .NET 3.5 projects -->
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v2.0"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

The following screenshot summarizes these options and provides a little more context to help:

[image: VB.NET Web Site XML Documentation Options]

Comment: I am using vb.net i can't see output path, and also i have created website not asp.net  project otherwise options are available for c# and asp.net  project.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with `/doc` option. From what I remember, it only works with XML comments in the code.

Comment: I have used below code to compile,  
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler
      language="vb;vbs;visualbasic"
      extension=".vb"
      type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider"
      compilerOptions="/doc:d:\XMLDOCS.xml"
      warningLevel="4" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>, 
it does generate xml file but comments are not added.

Comment: Are you using XML comments in VB? Ones that begin with '''? If not, I am not aware of any tool that can document it for you. May be nDoc (not sure though).

Comment: Take a look at Project properties -> Compile page to generate XML file.

Comment: I am not able to see that option, i guess because i have created a website. as you suggested i am able to generate xml file but it overwrites , it should append with xml comments.